# SetWindowsHookEx not calling my callback?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, keyboard-hook

Well I tried different solution to my problem but It just doesn't work.

I call SetWindowsHookExA and then when I press a key the messagebox is not shown. What to do?

this is my code (this is a DLL which is loaded by another DLL which is loaded by the program):

```
#include <Windows.h>

HINSTANCE gl_hThisInstance = NULL;
HHOOK hHook = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyHit(int code,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
         gl_hThisInstance = (HINSTANCE)hModule;
         hHook = SetWindowsHookExA(
            WH_KEYBOARD,
            KeyHit,
            //(HWND)gl_hThisInstance//not working
            0,//not working
            //(DWORD)gl_hThisInstance//not working
            //GetCurrentThreadId()//even not working with this
            0//not working
            );
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyHit(int code,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    MessageBox(0,"PRESSED","PRESSED",0);
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook,code,wParam,lParam);
}
```

Comment: Why the cast to HOOKPROC? If the compiler does not do this conversion silently, then the signature of KeyHit is wrong.

Comment: I deleted (HOOKPROC) and it compiles fine so I think that is not the problem

Comment: Why are you casting the `gl_hThisInstance`>  It's already the correct type...

Comment: When you say "`(DWORD)gl_hThisInstance//not working`" what does that mean?

Comment: Also the [first parameter to DllMain is `HINSTANCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx) so there's no reason to be casting that either.

Comment: //not working , means I tried that (compiled plugin) but it doesn't detect key presses.

Comment: This works for me `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, MsgProc, hiLib, GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, NULL));`

Comment: @Stan, in your application or DLL? and I'm talking about the WM_KEYBOARD

Comment: @GamErix Well, I supposed the message hook from my real app could work for you with keyboard hook as well. Yes, it's in a DLL, injected into external processes.

Answer (score 1):

I got issues with the hooking before. Not really an issue, but the way I did it was not supposed to.
First of all, you should have 2 exported functions from the DLL, `SetHook` and `RemoveHook`. The `SetHook` function will call the `SetWindowsHookEx()` from there. If you ever try to call the `SetWindowsHookEx()` from within a thread or `DLLMain` of your DLL, the function returns no errors, but the callback function will never be called. It took me sometimes to figure it out.

Posted here is my working code to catch `WH_GETMESSAGE`, you can reference from here.

Here is my working exported SetHook() function from the DLL.

```
bool __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall SetHook(DWORD myWnd)
{
    mySavedHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE,
        GetMsgProc,
        infoContainer.DllHModule,
        myWnd);

    int errorID = GetLastError();
    if (errorID != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to implement hook", "Failed", 0);
        MessageBoxA(NULL, to_string(errorID).c_str(), "Error ID", 0);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

`infoContainer.DllHModule`: instance of the DLL, which is the first parameter of `DllMain()`.
`myWnd:` is my Thread ID (not Process ID) - Get it from `GetWindowThreadProcessId(window_handle, NULL)`. To implement global hook, use 0 as `myWnd`.

And here is my callback function.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        LPMSG msg = (LPMSG)lParam;
        if (msg->message == WM_CALLFUNCTION)
        {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Receive WM_CALLFUNTION", "Good news", 0);
        }

    }
    //Doesn't matter, just call this function and return it.
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The callback function must have the `CALLBACK` keyword to work.

From the external application, call the `SetHook()` from the DLL and use the Thread ID as its param.

Comment: I don't know why the answer was edited by someone by just adding spaces before and after the code?

Comment: Hi, I have the same prob as the OP. You suggest that we export the `SetHook()` and `RemoveHook()` functions. My question is where to call these from. We may not call them from within `DllMain()` or a thread in the DLL because the hooks won't be called, as you said (and I can too confirm this). We may not call them from the app the DLL is injected into either, because we may not modify its code. Another app? It will have to call `LoadLibrary()\GetProcAddress()` then? Or how else? Could you please shed some light here?

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Did you find out where to call these functions from?

Comment: @Itay, the best way I have found (albeit probably not the best in general, or recommended) is to make a "launcher" .exe that will be calling an exported function in the .dll, which will be setting the hooks. And the hooks need to be placed in a shared data segment, using compiler/linker directives in the code, because the launcher and the application to be injected are two separate processes, and would thus otherwise be instantiated twice.